Can't export query result to storage blob with system managed identity
I am trying to export kusto query result to azure blob with managed identity. I followed steps provided by copilot and enabled system managed identity in kusto then assigned it Storage Blob Data Contributor role of my storage account. I also set the managed identity policy with 'AllowedUsages': 'All'. And grant the managed identity Database Viewer permissions. But when run the export command in kusto query, I got error : export_to_blob: authentication with a managed identity is disabled for this flow.
.export async to json (h@https://.blob.core.windows.net//;managed_identity=system) <| YourKustoQuery
Followed copilot steps and doc :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-export-with-managed-identity?view=azure-data-explorer&preserve-view=true&tabs=user-assigned%2Cazure-storage

Can you provide your full error?

Sure, the full error is: export_to_blob: Authentication with a Managed Identity is disabled for this flow. For more details, see https://aka.ms/managedIdentitySupportedFlows clientRequestId: Kusto.Web.KWE.Query;e33be46e-9ae1-469b-a960-a37de3104474;8541f539-a731-4c91-aee9-498d6927707b
Query:  .export async to json
(h@"https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/data/failure;managed_identity=system")
<| DBQuery

please check the below answer and let me know if you have any queries.


As per the documentation,

Impersonation, SAS token, Microsoft Entra access token and Storage account access key, only these are supported as authentication and authorization for the .export to cloud storage.

That is the reason why you are getting the above error as managed identity is not supported for the export to the cloud storage.
If you have access SAS or storage account access key, you can use it to achieve your requirement.
Using SAS:
.export
  async to json (
    h@"https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/test.json?<SAS_of_container>"
  )
  <| 
  mytable1


Using Storage account access key:
.export
  async to json (
    h@"https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/test.json;<access_key>"
  )
  <| 
  mytable1

If you only want to achieve your requirement using system managed identity, you can use external tables.
First assign the AllDatabaseadmin permission to your principal id. This is required to alter the managed identity policy.
Now, alter the database managed identity policy like below.
.alter-merge database <Database_name> policy managed_identity ```[
    {
      "ObjectId": "system",
      "AllowedUsages": "All"
    }
]```

Then, create the external table using the managed identity like below.
.create external table <external_table_name> (x:int, y:string) kind=blob dataformat=json
( 
    h@'https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/path/<filename>.json;managed_identity=system'
)


Now, export the Kusto table to this external table.
.export to table <external_table_name> <| mytable1;


Result JSON file in Blob:

